# Initialize global repository or in forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, initialization, repository

Until now we have always initialized the **repositories**, that containing MySql functions, at the beginning of each `Form`

Something like that:

```
public partial class FormTest: Form
{
    private readonly ProductRepository prodRep = new ProductRepository();
    private readonly UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
    private readonly CarRepository carRep = new CarRepository();
    private readonly RegistryRepository regRep = new RegistryRepository();

    public FormTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var product = prodRep.Get();

        var listUsers = userRep.GetAll();
    }
}
```

We were thinking of creating a new file with all the **repositories** inside and initializing it at the startup of the program.

1. Is it a suitable procedure?
2. Positive and negative aspects ?
3. Other methods?

Comment: Your question is too broad and context based to my opinion. It depends on the use

Comment: The question is too broad. In general, my advice is keeping them as short-lived objects, regardless of the place which you instantiate them . (Also consider reading about unit of work and repository pattern. For example take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which implements these pattern as an abstraction over entity framework. You will find it useful even for a Windows Forms Application.)